# Should there be self learning tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I have seen self learning tag in mathematics Stack Exchange. But this tag is not there in physics Stack Excahnge. I think there are many students who are learning new stuff by there own without help of any institution (like me).

normally it happens that when i ask some question, other users add homework tag. so i think if there is self learning tag, so they know other can know that whether it is homework question or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't actually matter whether or not the asker was assigned the problem as homework. The homework tag is for homework-like questions. These are questions whose purpose are not about resolving a conceptual difficulty, but instead about getting the right answer to a specific problem. Thus you can assign the homework tag without knowing if the problem actually is homework; homework-likeness is a property of the problem, not the asker.

I don't think people on this site care about whether or not you attend a university and I don't think they care about whether your question stems from a homework assignment or random curiosity. What they do care about is that your question addresses a conceptual issue that can be applied to many situations, so that the answer is useful to a wide audience and writing an answer is a good investment of time. The homework tag is supposed to indicate whether or not this is the case.

So I don't think we need a self-learner tag, because we don't care whether you go to a university or not, and we wouldn't need an "actual-homework" tag, because we don't care whether the problem is actually homework.

Here are some links to recent discussion about the homework tag for reference:

[About the proposal to ban homework](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5490/23785)

[What's the current status of the homework policy?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5375/23785)

Comment: *"I don't think people on this site care about whether or not you attend a university"*. But people often assume you have all the prior knowledge you learn at an university by the time you reach that subject you ask about. I sometimes get an answer I simply cannot understand because I'm not ready to understand it...

Answer (score 2):

## No.

[self-learning](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) would be a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and those are discouraged. In fact, [homework](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) is *also* a meta-tag, but [the site has voted to keep it](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5490/23785), and given it a [somewhat unusual meaning](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5375/23785).

(Note that a couple of those links are the same ones that [NowIGetTo... used](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5824/520)).