# (Why) does this particular question keep getting bumped up by Community?

Tags: discussion, support, community-user

I've noticed several (>~3) times over the past few months that the question [About the proposal to ban homework](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5490/about-the-proposal-to-ban-homework) has been bumped up the front page of Meta, on separate occasions. I don't think it happens that often at all, and I'm not sure whether it's a good thing on Meta.

Is there some way to see which questions have been bumped up by this process? Is this going on at all?

(On a related note, the [user page for Community on Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) states that it pokes up questions every hour. This is definitely false on Meta, so maybe it can be fixed?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> (On a related note, the user page for Community on Meta states that it pokes up questions every hour. This is definitely false on Meta, so maybe it can be fixed?)

It's true - with the caveat that it doesn't bump if there's nothing to bump. If there's only 1 question on the site that meets the criteria for bumping, then Community will bump it and *touch nothing else* for the next 30 days until it becomes eligible again.

And [as Qmechanic notes](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6276/why-does-this-particular-question-keep-getting-bumped-up-by-community/6277#6277), it rather appears that this is the only question that's been eligible for some time... And now even it isn't eligible anymore.

Comment: I feel bad for the community bot now. Nothing to bump...

Answer (score 5):

The post was likely bumped every month or so by the community bot because the post didn't have an upvoted answer. The post was bumped on Nov 12th, which is close to a multiple of 30 days from the original post on Feb 14th.

Comment: Maybe that'll fix it, then. Do mods have access to a list of bumped questions? You are right that there's a surprisingly small number of answered questions with no upvoted answers (I just took out [this one](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6104) and there's no more so far.) Hopefully someone from the Team can confirm that this is the behaviour?